# how to save and applythe userdefinefd theme at runtime

Tags: android, sqlite, android-theme

i wanna create three theme and apply  that theme to whole application and save that theme in DB on button click at run time.

So that when user restart the application that theme must be application whole application at run time.

So please help me...
Its very important for me.

Comment: Check this http://www.developer.com/ws/android/changing-your-android-apps-theme-dynamically.html

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy i have already tried this and i am facing problem after saving theme in database after that it doesn't switch between themes at run time. Help me regarding this.